# Reducing instruction count in arm

Tags: arm

I have this program that I am working on for school whose purpose is to add two matrices and store their result in a third matrix. Currently, the number of instructions is 1,003,034,420 when it is run with the driver (which is a .o file), but it needs to be under 1 billion. However, I am not sure how to do to this, since I have considered all of the instructions I use and all of them seem to be mandatory to have the program to work.

Note that I can't reduce the number of instructions with loop unrolling at this point since that comes later.

Here is the program:

```
/* This function has 5 parameters, and the declaration in the
   C-language would look like:

   void matadd (int **C, int **A, int **B, int height, int width)

   C, A, B, and height will be passed in r0-r3, respectively, and
   width will be passed on the stack. */

.arch armv7-a
.text
.align  2
.global matadd
.syntax unified
.arm
matadd:
   push  {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, lr}
   ldr   r4, [sp, #36]                 @ load width into r4
   mov   r5, #0                        @ r5 is current row index
row_loop: 
   mov   r6, #0                        @ r6 is the col, reset it for each new row
   cmp   r5, r3                        @ compare row with height
   beq   end_loops                     @ we have finished all of the rows
   ldr   r11, [r0, r5, lsl #2]         @ r11 is the current row array of C
   ldr   r7, [r1, r5, lsl #2]          @ r7 is the current row array of A
   ldr   r8, [r2, r5, lsl #2]          @ r8 is the current row array of B
                                       @ the left shifts are so that we skip
                                       @ 4 bytes since these are ints
                                       @ these do not change registers
col_loop:   
   cmp   r6, r4                        @ compare col with width
   beq   end_col                       @ we have finished this col
   ldr   r9, [r7, r6, lsl #2]          @ r9 is cur_row[col] of A
   ldr   r10, [r8, r6, lsl #2]         @ r10 is cur_row[col] of B
   add   r9, r9, r10                   @ r8 is A[row][col] + B[row][col]
   str   r9, [r11, r6, lsl #2]         @ store result of addition in C[row][col]
   add   r6, r6, #1                    @ increment col
   b     col_loop                      @ get next entry
end_col:
   add   r5, r5, #1                    @ increment row
   b     row_loop                      @ get next row
end_loops:   
   pop   {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, pc}
```

I thought there must be some instruction to combine cmp and b or something, but I can't seem to find it. Any pointers on how I can reduce the number of instructions?

Comment: The trick is to remove unconditional branches from the inner loop. Unroll to the next conditional branch

Comment: @RaymondChen How do you mean? Even if I do bne instead of b at the end of the inner loop it still has to compare each time. I sort of see what you mean in that I could combine the two branches somehow, but I don't see how to do this since they have to branch to different locations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to remove unconditional branches from the inner loop.

```
loop_start:
    cmp x, y
    beq loop_exit

    blah blah blah

    b loop_start
loop_exit:
```

Notice that every time through the loop, you have an unconditional branch (`b loop_start`). Avoid the branch by inlining the branch target until the next conditional branch.

```
loop_start:
    cmp x, y
    beq loop_exit

loop_middle:
    blah blah blah

    ; was "b loop_start" but we just copy the instructions
    ; starting at "loop_start" up to the conditional branch

    cmp x, y
    beq loop_exit

    ; and then jump to the instruction after the inlined portion
    b loop_middle
loop_exit:
```

At this point, the `beq` is just a branch over a branch, so it can be replaced with a reverse-sense branch.

```
loop_start:
    cmp x, y
    beq loop_exit

loop_middle:
    blah blah blah

    cmp x, y

    ; "beq loop_exit" followed by "b loop_middle" is equivalent to this
    bne loop_middle

loop_exit:
```

There are two opportunities for this optimization in your code.

(Don't forget to cite this web page when submitting your solution, in order to avoid charges of academic dishonesty.)